# Notation in two-dimensional DCT

Tags: dct

In [this DCT video](https://youtu.be/DS8N8cFVd-E?t=77) isn't $X^c$ the input image and what does the superscript $c$ signify?
Why do they call $X^c$ "DCT coefficients " although it's the input image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the inverse DCT.
$x[m,n]$ is the **image**, $X[k,l]$ are the **coefficients**.

Comment: I'm surprised. The video doesn't say it's the inverse. But it makes sense...

Comment: Actually, I'm not perfectly happy with the answer. Look at the scanned page from Koppel, Eisen and Ribeiro posted by @Laurent Duval. There the inverse transform uses $cos$ of $[m∗pi((2k+1)/2M]$ whereas in the video it is $[k∗pi((2m+1)/2M]$. So $k$ and $m$ change places! Which one is the REAL formula of inverse DCT?

Comment: @Suvi I agree, it’s confusing: Looks like $m$ And $k$ Move around from definition to definition: [matlab inverse 2D DCT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/idct2.html)

Comment: I do think my answer is valid: Matlab has the same equation as in the video, so I’d say that’s the correct expression.  Not sure why Laurent’s paper shows different indices.

Comment: Also [this link](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dct.html#bvk_spb) and [this link](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node231.html) seem to support your position. In [this video](https://youtu.be/Q2aEzeMDHMA?t=682) they call the inverse transformation DCT-III and the first link provides the same formula for DCT-III as what was seen in the [original video](https://youtu.be/DS8N8cFVd-E?t=70). But still don't understand why the book tells otherwise. Maybe you can use either one for direct transformation as long as you use the opposite formula for the inverse?

Comment: @Suvi that's an interesting thought. Again, not well-versed enough in DCT to answer without spending a little time on it, which I don't have too much of at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Jdip can be accepted. As a complement, such a notation is fairly common, though I am more used to a subscript ($X_C$ instead of $X^c$). A classical convention is:

- $x$ (lowercase) denotes input signals/images
- $X$ (capital) denotes transformed signals/images, also called coefficients.

To be more explicit regarding the action on $x$ of  a transformation or basis $C$ (here DCT-II), the transformed coefficients are denoted $X_C$ as "$x$ transformed with respect to $C$". You can find more details in: [The Discrete Cosine Transform and JPEG](https://ese2240.seas.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/900_image_lab-1.pdf), Alec Koppel, Mark Eisen, Alejandro Ribeiro, 2021. Excerpt:

[image: The Discrete Cosine Transform and JPEG]

Comment: The lower formula for $\vec{x_C}$ is different than in the video. In the video we take the cosine of  $[k*pi((2m+1)/2M]$, in the book it's $[m*pi((2k+1)/2M]$. So k and m change places, why?

Comment: In the video, I am not sure of which DCT the speaker is talking about. He does not talk about an "inverse DCT", maybe he is using a direct one.

Comment: [matlab inverse DCT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/idct2.html#f4-245349) Looks like $m$ and $k$ are inter-changeable? Not really versed in 2D DCT so can't really provide any explanation...